# Searching mysql database with multiple PHP queries instead of OR operator

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search

TLDR; I'm trying to get some 'fuzzy' results from a search query that fails to come up with things that are actually there.

**The problem:**

This specific setup is in Wordpress land, but that's not decisively relevant to the issue. There's this longstanding problem with wordpress search – that it uses `AND` operators, not `OR`. This leads to the following problem:

Some people (not necessarily many but often key customers) will search for `john+doe+jane` and find nothing. Had they searched for just `john+doe` they'd have found a ton of results. Or maybe they simply misspell a word or, worse, it was misspeled in the article etc.  I need this fixed somehow.

I tried all the plugins, but they either fare worse than the default search or they just won't work (likely because I also made other customizations to the search, but  I can't go back on those). So eventually I tried to work my own way out.

I know next to nothing about databases (and not much about Wordpress hooks either), so I tried to move the `OR` issue to php.

My thinking: First of all, are there quite a few search results? If true, trust Wordpress search that it has done its job for 99+ percent of cases. But are there very few or none at all? Then there may be a problem. Step in, try and fix it!

So, for when there are fewer than 10 results, I made this fallback script:

**The solution:**

```
// [Wordpress search loop ran before this]
// find out how many results below the target
$missing = 10 - count($posts); 
// or `$missing = 10 - $wp_query->found_posts` - all the same – but already constructed this `$posts` array which I'll need later anyway.

// only do it if you actually need it (less than 10 search results from WP)

if ($missing > 0) {

// give each search term its own life

$terms = explode(" ",$string); 
// where `$string = get_query_var('s')` // or `$string = explode("+",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` in a more generic environment.

// ...

$weight = array();
$results = array();

// start some nasty nested foreaches to search for each term

foreach ($terms as $term) {

// first, get this huge array of posts // wordpress stuff   
    $results = get_posts(array('s' => $term,'numberposts' => 10));

// then iterate through each of them
    foreach ($results as $result) {

// (drop mostly useless one-or-two-letter words)
    if (strlen($term) < 3) continue;

// reward each occurence with a biscuit, they'll prove useful later*
    $matches[$result->ID] += 1; 

// don't let any term become a neverending story (stop inner foreach)
    if(count($matches) == 10) break;
    }

// stop the game altogether – by now we should have just enough (stop outer foreach)
    if(count($matches) > 100) break;
}

// sort the results nicely by biscuits awarded 
// *(so if one term came up 3/4 times it goes before one that one that came up 2/4)
arsort($matches);

// to make arrays compatible it's ok to forget the exact biscuit numbers (they don't really matter anymore)
$matches = array_keys($matches);

// if Wordpress found you first we don't need you, you're already up there in the original loop
$fallbacks = array_diff($matches,$posts);

// [standard wordpress loop]
$fallback = new WP_Query( array (
    'post__in' => $fallbacks,
    'orderby' => post__in,
// add just enough to get to ten
    'posts_per_page' => $missing    
    )
);
    if ( $fallback->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $fallback->have_posts() ) { 
    $fallback->the_post(); 
// [magic goes here]
        } 
    }
}
```

Does the job. However...

**The issues I'm aware of:**

1. Performance: It takes long but not too long. Page (openresty/nginx+redis+varnish) would load in .8s instead of the usual .3 cached or .4-.5 busted*.
2. Bad bots doing bad stuff: There's merciless sanitizing in WP and there's decent rate-limiting on the webserver, throwing nice 400's and 429's**.

**The issues I'm not aware of:**

1. *Not live yet so I don't now how it would scale. Too many at once – what could happen? Can that sort of nested foreach kill a database?
2. **I'd hate if someone still manages to find a weak spot before I do. Any in sight?

Comment: The User needs to understand the _technical_ difference between `AND` and `OR`.  (English is quite sloppy in its meaning.)  You need to provide a way for the user to pick between the two, then you may need to create a "raw" query to do what is asked for.

Comment: Is the User able to specify something like `("John" OR "Jane") AND "Doe"?

Comment: UX wise it can be no more than one (input) box and one (submit) button. Anything extra would be more trouble than it is right now.
And Wordpress doesn't make things easy at all, they're in the "[blunt] decisions, not [reasonable] options" rabbit-hole... So I'd have to dig into the core for raw database operations, both of which are above my paygrade.